# Cannot upgrade Node.js using n

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to update Node.js on Ubuntu serever 14.04 using `n`.
`n` upgrades but the version is still the same:

```
root@0e2dbaa3db85:/home# node -v
v0.10.25

root@0e2dbaa3db85:/home# n 0.10.33
  install : node-v0.10.33
    mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/0.10.33
    fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.33/node-v0.10.33-linux-x64.tar.gz
installed : v0.10.33

root@0e2dbaa3db85:/home# node -v
v0.10.25
```

Do I have to tell `n` which version to use as default?
I've tried `n latest`, it installs 0.12.0 but `node -v` outputs `0.10.25` again.

What should I do?

Answer (score 10):

On occasion the n package won't install the links for node, and the selection won't allow you to select any version installed by n.

When that happens, you need to install an "n" version of node so the selector will allow you to choose.

Here is what I had to do.

1. **Use n to install a node version.**

   ```
   # n stable

    install : node-v5.10.1
      mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/5.10.1
      fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v5.10.1/node-v5.10.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
   ######################################################################## 100.0%
      installed : v0.10.42
   ```
2. **Select the node version from the install directory**
   In this case it is located at:

   ```
   /usr/local/n/versions/node/5.10.1/bin/node
   ```
3. **Replace existing node link with new node version**

   ```
   cd /bin
   mv node node_old
   ln -s /usr/local/n/versions/node/5.10.1/bin/node
   ```

At this point node should work, and n should allow you to select version.

Answer (score 8):

- Resolved by `nvm`.
- I faced the same issue with you. I could not change node version with `n` because I installed `nvm` and used `nvm` to manage node versions before.
- I resolved the issue by execute `nvm` command. For example: `nvm install 11.8.0` then check node version `node -v`. Tada it works.

Answer (score 2):

`n 0.10.33` will install that version of node, but you still haven't selected it. After installing, simply execute `n` and pick the version you want to use.

`n latest` will install or activate the latest version of node. Run it twice to use node 0.12.0

[Documentation](https://github.com/tj/n#installing-binaries).

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue, where I select a different version or even download a new version with n and it still shows the initial installation before I started using n. This worked for me:

1. Unlink

   sudo unlink /usr/bin/node
2. Run n again to choose the node version.
   After this two steps it worked

Answer (score 0):

From what I can read from the [n readme](https://github.com/tj/n), you need to call `n <version>` to install, and then run `n` with no arguments, so a version picker will be shown:

> Type n to prompt selection of an installed node. Use the up / down arrow to navigate, and press enter or the right arrow to select, or ^C to cancel:
>
> (...)
>
> Commands:
>   n <version>    Install node <version>

However, if you run `n latest`, it will install **or** activate the latest version:

> n latest            Install or activate the latest node release

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the simbolic link to node to the npm global folder.

1. sudo unlink /usr/bin/node
2. sudo ln -rs PATHTO/.npm-global/node/bin/nodee node

in my case, my path to npm-global dir was on my home. So the full path was /home/rafael/.npm-global/node/bin/node

After this, check if is allrigth:

1. node -v //return current node version
2. n stable //install the stable current version
3. node -v //will return the new version installed
4. n 8 //install the version 8 for test
5. node -v //will return the 8 version

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had the active version set via Homebrew, so n wasn't overriding it.

I had to use the following:

```
brew uninstall node && sudo n stable
```